JVM cannot find Agent_OnLoad in agent lib
I am coding a Java Agent library. However, the JVM cannot find Agent_OnLoad function even if I have explicitly exported it in my C++ code.
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
    Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* reserved)
{
    return JNI_OK;
}

It then says Could not find Agent_OnLoad function in the agent library: ./FuncTest.dll. The start-up command line is java -agentpath:./FuncTest.dll -jar .\helloworld.jar
Using Visual Studio 2022, Corretto 17.0.8

Did you check your actual DLL to make sure the export is present and decorated correctly? You may need to use a .DEF file to name the export properly. It may be getting exported like _Agent_OnLoad or _Agent_OnLoad@12 instead of just plain Agent_OnLoad

Thanks @RemyLebeau, I looked up the DLL's functions using IDA and found out that the name was mangled.

Name decoration is applied to the exported function name.
By editing it to
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
        Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* reserved)
    {
        return JNI_OK;
    }
}

solves the problem.
See How to specify a "clean" name of DLL exports? for a detailed answer.

That is literally the same code you posted originally. Why did you edit your question to change the code just to post the original code in this answer?

@RemyLebeau The original code is simplified from my project. When simplifying the code I modified it's structure wrongly.
